# after implement jwt autho in my spring boot application,Ive cors problem again

Tags: java, spring, jwt, cors

I had no issues with cors before doing the jwt implementation, but just after i implemented it, ive this cors error and i dunno how to fix it:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'x' from origin 'http://localhost:52151' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

my backend is built with spring and deployed in heroku and my front is in angular.

**HibernateProjectAplication:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(HibernateProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("DELETE", "POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }


}
```

**UserController:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    private final userService userService;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    public UserController(userService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    userRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenUtil JwtTokenUtil;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            User newUser = userService.createNewUser(user);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<User> userLogin(@RequestBody User user) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String token = JwtTokenUtil.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        if (userService.findByEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword())) {

            User userBean = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);

    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();

    }
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

**JwtTokenUtil:**

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil {
    @Value("${jwttoken.secret}")
    private String jwtTokenSecret;
    @Value("${jwttoken.expiration}")
    private long jwtTokenExpiration;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
        User userPrincipal = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userPrincipal.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtTokenExpiration))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtTokenSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(jwtTokenSecret)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        }catch(UnsupportedJwtException exp) {
            System.out.println("claimsJws argument does not represent Claims JWS" + exp.getMessage());
        }catch(MalformedJwtException exp) {
            System.out.println("claimsJws string is not a valid JWS" + exp.getMessage());
        }catch(SignatureException exp) {
            System.out.println("claimsJws JWS signature validation failed" + exp.getMessage());
        }catch(ExpiredJwtException exp) {
            System.out.println("Claims has an expiration time before the method is invoked" + exp.getMessage());
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException exp) {
            System.out.println("claimsJws string is null or empty or only whitespace" + exp.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        Claims claims =Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtTokenSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();

    }
}
```

Any Ideas how can i fix this??? THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE :)))

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to add wildcards after the "/api" mapping.

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH")
                    .allowedHeaders("*").allowedOrigins("*").exposedHeaders(
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "Access-Control-Max-Age", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
        }
    };
}
```